# python run file from other directory, missing icon

Tags: python, linux, path, pipenv

I make an app located in ~/program/00-python/crypsys/main.py
this file uses Icon.PNG located in the same directory

When i run from home (~) i dont get the icon:

```
python ~/program/00-python/crypsys/main.py
```

The question:

Do I have to set a special path inside python script?

Answer (score 1):

You can give full path to your `icon.png` or use the `__file__` attribute to find the path of your `.py` file and use it for finding `icon.png`:

```
import os
dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
icon_path = os.path.join(dirname, "icon.png")
```